# Creating default value row in Redshift dimension table to prevent null values in reports

Tags: data-warehouse, amazon-redshift

I am porting over a data warehouse schema and default data load from MySQL which was used for initial development to Redshift for production. The initial default data was created as a row in the dimension tables with a -1 value set in the auto increment column as per http://www.kimballgroup.com/2010/10/design-tip-128-selecting-default-values-for-nulls/.

Upon moving the schema to Redshift, the column should be changed to identity from auto_increment in order to preserve the database primary key generation, but this no longer allows an insert into the identity column returning

```
ERROR: cannot set an identity column to a value
SQL state: 0A000
```

Should the ETL loading job take responsibility for auto-incrementing the dimension key in this instance, or is there another to create the insert value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I know, overriding the autogenerated values does not work for `INSERT`. If you have the possibility to upload your data to S3, you can use Redshift's `COPY` command to load data from S3 into the table. It let's you specify the option `EXPLICIT_IDS`, e.g.:

```
COPY your_table from 's3://path_to_your/data.csv' CREDENTIALS '' EXPLICIT_IDS;
```

From the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-conversion.html#copy-explicit-ids):

> Use EXPLICIT_IDS with tables that have IDENTITY columns if you want to override the autogenerated values with explicit values from the source data files for the tables. If the command includes a column list, that list must include the IDENTITY columns to use this parameter. The data format for EXPLICIT_IDS values must match the IDENTITY format specified by the CREATE TABLE definition.